# Spring @autowired does not work

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, autowired

I have a problem with spring DI via annotations, here is my app:

```
@Service
public class Test {

    @Autowired
    private GpsPointEntityDao gpsPointEntityDao;

    public void test() {

        if (gpsPointEntityDao == null)
            System.out.println("It's null!\n" + gpsPointEntityDao);

    }
}
```

generic interface:

```
public interface GenericDao<T extends DomainObject> {

    public T find(long id);

    public List<T> getAll();

    public void save(T object) throws DataAccessException;

    public void delete(T object) throws DataAccessException;

}
```

concrete interface:

```
public interface GpsPointEntityDao extends GenericDao<GpsPointEntity> {}
```

abstract implementation:

```
abstract class AbstractGenericDaoJpa<T extends DomainObject> implements GenericDao<T> {

    private final Class<T> entityType;

    protected EntityManager entityManager;

    public AbstractGenericDaoJpa() {
        this.entityType = (Class<T>) GenericTypeResolver.resolveTypeArgument(getClass(), GenericDao.class);
    }

    @PersistenceContext
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public T find(long id) {
        return entityManager.find(entityType, id);
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public List<T> getAll() {
        return entityManager.createQuery("SELECT e FROM " + entityType.getName() + " e").getResultList();
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void save(T object) throws DataAccessException {
        entityManager.persist(object);
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void delete(T object) throws DataAccessException {
        entityManager.remove(object);
    }

}
```

concrete class:

```
@Repository
public class GpsPointEntityDaoJpa extends AbstractGenericDaoJpa<GpsPointEntity> implements GpsPointEntityDao {}
```

And my appcontext:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
      p:dataSource-ref="basicDataSource"/>

<bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
      p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory"/>

<tx:annotation-driven mode="proxy" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>
```

The result of app is:

**It's null!**

I have been spending all day for searching the problem but unsuccessfully. Where someone sees a problem?

I found this message in logs:

```
INFO  org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext - Bean 'entityManagerFactory' of type [class org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
```

Comment: How do you access your test class? Could you show the code were you actually create and use the object?

Comment: Are all classes in the `com.test.*` packages?

Comment: <pre>
public class Service {

    private static ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext-persistence.xml");

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Test test = new Test();
        test.test();
    }

}
</pre>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see a problem with that. With roughly the same code as you posted, I ran this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test bean = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/applicationContext.xml").getBean(Test.class);
    bean.test();
}
```

The Test bean was injected correctly. I can make my test project available if you want to take a look. Are you sure you're getting an injected version of Test? How are you obtaining it?

**Edit:** Your instance isn't being injected because you're instantiating it yourself instead of letting Spring do it. Unless you [use AspectJ to inject objects](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-atconfigurable), Spring can/will *only* inject objects that it is managing. When you call `new Test()`, you're not getting the instance from Spring, and Spring doesn't know anything about that instance you've created.

Comment: Thanks!  I should probably read the WHOLE documentation before I go about posting wrong answers! :)

Comment: @Ryan Stewart: It would nice for you if you gave me your test project.
Actually I have two app configs, one is that above, and second one:

<p>
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/*.properties"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="sk.wimc.test.app"/>
    <import resource="basicDataSource.xml"/>

</p>

Comment: I load the context like this:

<b>private static ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext*.xml");</b>

Comment: I don't understand this, when I get the object from context like this:
**Test test = ctx.getBean(Test.class);** all works fine, but if I do: **Test test = new Test();** there are null reference in autowired field.

Answer (score -1):

you can use the @Resource annotation instead of @Autowire.

Try whether this works.